# Wait Apollo client queries in loop

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a problem with waiting queries to be ready before going to next.

I do not have an idea why it loop through immediately even there are `.then` piping and `await`.

My Apollo client query:

```
import pkg from '@apollo/client'
import * as fs from 'fs'

const { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } = pkg

const cmsUrl = 'HIDDEN'

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: cmsUrl,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})

const locales = [
  {
    name: 'finnish',
    id: 'fi',
  },
  {
    name: 'swedish',
    id: 'fi',
  },
  {
    name: 'english',
    id: 'fi',
  },
]

const fetchTranslations = locale =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    client
      .query({
        query: gql`
          query {
            translations(first: 10000, locales: ${locale.id}) {
              translation
              translationId
              locale
            }
          }
        `,
      })
      .then(result => {
        const parsedData = result.data.translations.reduce((acc, curr) => {
          const translation = curr.translation
          const translationId = curr.translationId
          acc[translationId] = translation

          return acc
        }, {})
        resolve(parsedData)
      })
  })

const fetchAllTranslations = async () => {
  for (const locale of locales) {
    console.log(`Fetching translations for ${locale.name}...`)
    await fetchTranslations(locale).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      fs.writeFileSync(`src/translation/${locale.id}.json`, '')
      fs.writeFileSync(`src/translation/${locale.id}.json`, JSON.stringify(response))
    })
  }
  console.log('All translations are fetched')
}
fetchAllTranslations()
```

Do you know where the problem is, why it loops throughly and does not wait the queries resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're `await`ing something which is not a promise because it already has a `.then()` handler. Use `await` to get the response.

```
const fetchAllTranslations = async () => {
  for (const locale of locales) {
    const fName = `src/translation/${locale.id}.json`;
    console.log(`Fetching translations for ${locale.name}...`)
    const response = await fetchTranslations(locale);
    fs.writeFileSync(fName, '');
    fs.writeFileSync(fName, JSON.stringify(response));
    })
  }
  console.log('All translations are fetched')
};
fetchAllTranslations()
```